# Why should fix 'this' when return a function?

Tags: javascript, return, closures, this

I read the piece of code in a book,

```
Function.prototype.before = function(beforefn){
    var _self = this;
    return function(){
        beforefn.apply(this,arguments);
        return _self.apply(this,arguments);
    }
}
```

when execute 
`beforefn.apply(this,arguments);`and`return _self.apply(this,arguments);`,I think even without fix 'this' it will get the same result.

```
function test(){
    return function(){
        alert(this.foo);
    }
}
var o1 = {
    foo:"foo",
    test:test(),
}

o1.test(); //alert foo
```

So what is the purpose to fix this of the author?
P.S This is the first time ask question in StackOverflow,forgive my bad English.Thanks

Thanks for noticing my question! I would rewrite like this:

`Function.prototype.before = function(beforefn){
    var _self = this;
    return function(){
        beforefn(arguments);
        return arguments.callee;
    }
}`

Comment: What do you mean, "without fix this"? Can you show how you would rewrite the `before` method?

Comment: What's the `var foo = "test"` supposed to do in your `test` function? It's never used.

Comment: @Bergi yes it's useless,I delete it

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for reminding,I have rewrite the cod in my question.

Comment: Hm, `return arguments.callee` (besides being deprecated) doesn't call the original function `_self` any more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.apply(this, …)` doesn't *fix* the thisArg - in contrast, it even makes it dynamic, using the current dynamic `this` from the returned function. Have a look at how well it works:

```
function test(){
   alert(this.foo);
}
var o1 = {
    foo: "bar",
    test: test.before(function() { console.log(this); })
};
o1.test(); // logs o1, alerts "bar"
o1.test.call({}); // logs the empty object, alerts undefined
```

You'd only fix the `this` argument of `_self` if you *didn't* pass the current `this`, as in

```
Function.prototype.before = function(beforefn){
    var fn = this;
    return function() {
        beforefn.apply(null, arguments);
        return fn.apply(null, arguments);
    }
}
```

where `o1.test()` would not work any more. Of course, `apply` is still necessary to pass a variable amount of arguments to the function.

Comment: Thanks a lot,man,I was confused about apply() but now I understand.Thanks again!